# Why my integer literal is not being promoted to long type when there is another long value in the expression?

Tags: java, types

Code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long i = 4294967296l;
        System.out.println(i + 65536 * 65536);
        System.out.println(i + 65536L * 65536);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4294967296
8589934592
```

It looks like in the first `System.out.println` statement, `65536 * 65536` is evaluated as `int` type as a result of which it wraps to `0`.

I want to know why in this statement, the numbers are not promoted to `long`. I thought that the presence of the long variable `i` in this statement would have been sufficient to promote `65536` to long as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Multiplication is evaluated before addition (operators precedence), so first `65536 * 65536` is evaluated as int multiplication (since both operands are `int` literals) and the result is promoted to long for the addition of a `long` and an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of a multiplicative expression is the promoted type of its operands.
If the promoted type is int or long, then integer arithmetic is performed.
and The type of the unary plus expression is the promoted type of the operand.

any further clarification please use the link

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3